# At what rate does a wet clothing decrease the temperature of a human body?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

The question is required for my project, but it is frankly too hard for me...
The variables that I consider are:
Human Body: 36.5(C)
Air: 20(C)
Sunlight Intensity: 1,368(W/m^2)
Wind Speed: 20(km/hr)
(Assume that the wet clothing has negligible clothing density/heat conduction, although I'm not sure if this is the correct assumption...)

My strategy was:

1. Calculate the temperature change of the wet clothing from the sunlight and wind
2. Calculate the rate of heat conduction from the wet clothing to the human body

I might be able to do 2. myself, but 1. is impossible...

Comment: It appears to me that you do not have enough information to determine a rate of heat removal without making certain assumptions outside of what you have presented above. To begin with, perhaps the greatest factor in air cooling is evaporation, and yet you do not appear to have a figure for some measure of humidity. Would you be able to clarify exactly what the question is asking?

Comment: Sorry for the inconsiderate question. The assumed condition is the summer time, so I assume humidity is 25%. I'm trying to find a function with variables of sunlight intensity, wind speed, and air temperature, with the output of rate of heat conduction

Comment: This question probably has too many variables to answer appropriately.  What is the orientation of the person with respect to the solar radiation (e.g., solar flux is dependent on angle)?  Is the person laying down or standing (the cross-sectional area exposed to wind and sun will definitely affect the answer, and that area may be different for wind vs. sun)?  How fast is the wind blowing (forced convection is involved)?  What is the shape of the person involved?  What type of clothing is the person wearing?  What is the emissivity of that clothing?  What temperature are the surroundings at?

Comment: Each part of the clothing will be exposed to a different angle from the sun, and some of the clothing will be in shade.  The time of year, time of day, and altitude will all affect solar intensity.  Relative humidity will affect evaporation rate.  Regarding temperature of the human body, do you mean core temperature or skin temperature?  There are too many unknowns to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, human body temperature is maintained by the body. If it is lower, body will burn some fat to keep it up. If it is high, the body will do something like sweating.

Wearing a wet cloth in wind can remove the heat from the body. The amount of heat may be calculated. 
1. convection heat transfer by wind between water (a thin layer) to air
2. mass transportation of water from water to air (evaporation)
3. radiation heat to the water
4. latent heat due to mass transportation
5. heat transfer between the body and the water (depends on how do you wear it)
6. temperature change of the water in cloth.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple problem, so you shouldn’t try to solve it analytically.

Instead, you should rely on the literature. There are [reports](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a136654.pdf),  [reviews](http://www.iloencyclopaedia.org/part-vi-16255/heat-and-cold/76-42-heat-and-cold/heat-exchange-through-clothing) and [web summaries](https://www.princeton.edu/~oa/safety/hypocold.shtml) that can provide information to get you started at whatever level of detail you need.